# How to find the interior angle of two triangles intersected in a certain point?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows an equilateral triangle $\triangle=EBC$
> and $\angle\,EDC=70^{\circ}$. Using this condition find $x^{\circ}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&30^{\circ}\\
2.&15^{\circ}\\
3.&20^{\circ}\\
4.&25^{\circ}\\
5.&35^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

This problem has left me going in circles. Can someone help me here?.

The only thing which I could spot was $EB=BC=EC$ and $\angle\,EAC=20^{\circ}$

But that's it. I don't know what else can be done to identify or spot the required angle. Does this thing requires some sort of construction or any identity such as congruence or something?. I just can't find any.

**Please include a drawing in the answer** or sketch to spot where to look for, as I am not that good to identifying the sides and angles from only looking algebraic expressions.

Comment: Can you make anything of the fact that $\triangle EDC$ is isosceles?

Answer (score 1):

As you requested, the following is your figure with several extra degree values being specified, and congruent side lengths marked with a short line segment roughly perpendicular to the side.

[image: OP's triangle diagram with extra degrees and congruent sides marked]

Since $\measuredangle EDC = 70^{\circ}$, then the sum of angles in $\triangle ECD$ being $180^{\circ}$ means $\measuredangle CED = 180^{\circ} - 70^{\circ} - 40^{\circ} = 70^{\circ}$. Thus, $\triangle ECD$ is isosceles (as [Brian Tung](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/224454/brian-tung)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882651/how-to-find-the-interior-angle-of-two-triangles-intersected-in-a-certain-point/3882722#comment8007323_3882651) indicated), with $\left| EC \right| = \left| DC \right|$.

The stated detail of $\triangle EBC$ being equilateral means $\left| EC \right| = \left| BC \right|$, giving $\left| DC \right| = \left| BC \right|$, so $\triangle BCD$ is also isosceles. With $\measuredangle BCD = 40^{\circ} + 60^{\circ} = 100^{\circ}$, this means $\measuredangle CBD = \measuredangle CDB = \frac{180^{\circ} - 100^{\circ}}{2} = 40^{\circ}$. Finally, $x = \measuredangle EDC - \measuredangle CDB = 70^{\circ} - 40^{\circ} = 30^{\circ}$, i.e., alternative $1$.